# Can't parse Json text with unicode codes with Python 3.7

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, character-encoding

This should be a piece of cake, but I'm new to Python and I can't seem to understand how this should done:

I have a JSON file that I got by retrieving my personal data from Facebook, this is just a chunk of the file:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1575826804,
    "attachments": [

    ],
    "data": [
      {
        "post": "This is a test line with character \u00c3\u00ad and \u00c3\u00b3"
      },
      {
        "update_timestamp": 1575826804
      }
    ],
    "title": "My Name"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1575826526,
    "attachments": [

    ],
    "data": [
      {
        "update_timestamp": 1575826526
      }
    ],
    "title": "My Name"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1575638718,
    "data": [
      {
        "post": "This is another test line with character \u00c3\u00ad and \u00c3\u00b3 and line breaks\n"
      }
    ],
    "title": "My Name escribi\u00c3\u00b3 en la biograf\u00c3\u00ada de Someone."
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1575561399,
    "attachments": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "external_context": {
              "url": "https://youtu.be/lalalalalalaaeeeE"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "data": [
      {
        "update_timestamp": 1575561399
      }
    ],
    "title": "My Name"
  }
]
```

The file has many unicode codes like "\u00c3\u00ad" that I need to convert to ASCII representations. I tryed to parse this JSON file and load it as a Python object with the "json" library, first I did:

```
with open("test.json") as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

    print(type(data))
    print(data[0])

    # output:
    # <class 'list'>
    # {'timestamp': 1575826804, 'attachments': [], 'data': [{'post': 'This is a test line with 
    # character Ã\xad and Ã³'}, {'update_timestamp': 1575826804}], 'title': 'My Name'}
```

Although I get a list object from json.load(), the accented characters are wrong: "Ã\xad" and "Ã³". Then I did:

```
with open("test.json", encoding='unicode-escape') as fp:
    txt = fp.read().encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
    data = json.loads(txt)

print(type(data))
print(data[2])
```

This seccond attemp will work only if the json string doesn't contain any character line newlines "\n" or ":" within a JSON value, but in cases like mine it will throw:

```
JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 33 column 82 (char 560)
```

Character 560 is the trailing "\n" inside a JSON value "post":

```
  {
    "post": "This is another test line with character \u00c3\u00ad and \u00c3\u00b3 and line breaks\n"
  }
```

How should I correctly load this JSON with Unicodes? Is it replacing the unicode strings for ASCII characters the only way around?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hmmm, weird. `\u00c3\u00b3` is actually Ã³ in Unicode.

Comment: @IvánC.: and when parsed as UTF8, it would be the character `ò`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use 'raw_unicode_escape'.

```
import json
with open("j.json", encoding='raw_unicode_escape') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read().encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode())
    print(data[0])

OUT: {'timestamp': 1575826804, 'attachments': [], 'data': [{'post': 'This is a test line with character í and ó'}, {'update_timestamp': 1575826804}], 'title': 'My Name'}
```

Does this help?

Comment: This made it work! Now unicode unicode codes are being decoded correctly, thanks!